# Prettier not respecting singleAttributePerLine setting in prettierrc config

Tags: format, prettier

I am using Prettier for formatting my HTML code, and I'm encountering an issue where Prettier continues to break the attributes onto new lines, even though I have explicitly set `singleAttributePerLine` to `false` in my `.prettierrc` configuration file.

Here is an example of my `.prettierrc` file:

```
{
    "printWidth": 120,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "useTabs": true,
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "semi": true,
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore",
    "singleAttributePerLine": false
}
```

Despite setting `singleAttributePerLine` to `false` (also the default value), Prettier still formats my HTML code with each attribute on a separate line. This behaviour is not what I intended, as I would like to keep all attributes on the same line for better readability.

Prettier formats this code:

```
<ng-template #formAction>
  <ng-container *ngIf="userService.isImplementationManager()">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-link no-underline hover:underline text-error mr-3" (click)="disableImplementation()"
      type="button">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-link no-underline hover:underline" type="submit"
      [disabled]="implementationDetailForm.invalid">Save</button>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

to this code:

```
<ng-template #formAction>
    <ng-container *ngIf="userService.isImplementationManager()">
        <button
            class="btn btn-sm btn-link no-underline hover:underline text-error mr-3"
            (click)="disableImplementation()"
            type="button"
        >
            Cancel
        </button>
        <button
            class="btn btn-sm btn-link no-underline hover:underline"
            type="submit"
            [disabled]="implementationDetailForm.invalid"
        >
            Save
        </button>
    </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

I have also verified that my Prettier version is up to date, and I am using the latest version available.

Comment: It seems the `singleAttributePerLine` is working only on native HTML tags, but for the custom angular components, it keeps breaking the every attribute to new line

Comment: I hope it supports react and angular components.